# Should I delete incorrect answers? Will doing so give me rep?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, behavior

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536293/c-best-way-to-call-tostring-on-an-object/1536299#1536299) and then realized the answer was just plain wrong, so I deleted it.

Now the answer seems to have a score of three, and I earned the the "Disciplined" badge. Have I gotten points for deleting my own answer, or were the points awarded before the deletion?

Also, was deleting the "right" choice, or should I have added a comment like "oops, this doesn't work..."?

Answer (score 6):

Those votes were issued *while* you were closing. No problem, you will loose them again if there ever is a recalc of your score.

And if an answer is wrong, just delete it or correct it. Leaving faulty answers (with a note) isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You don't get any points. You've lost 30 points. This is not immediately visible, but after a [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) or automatic reputation recalc, this is visible in your total reputation.

If an answer is after all utterly wrong, then deleting is definitely the right way. That's also exactly why the badge is been awarded if you do it for the first time.